# Why is my sound making my game lag in Swift Spritekit?

Tags: swift, audio, avfoundation

I have this sound effect when my hero node collects a coin and there is this small hiccup in my game. Its not smooth like in other games when there is sound involved when collecting a coin. What am I doing wrong? Heres my code for the sound:

```
  class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

   var coinSound =  NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("coin", ofType: "wav")!)
   var coinAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

   coinAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: coinSound, error: nil)
   coinAudioPlayer.pause()
   }

   if firstBody.categoryBitMask == HeroCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == CoinCategory {

   coinAudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
   coinAudioPlayer.play()
   coinAudioPlayer.currentTime = NSTimeInterval(1.0)
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using [`SKAction.playSoundFileNamed`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:)?

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. Is there more to the code or is it just that. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`SKAction.playSoundFileNamed`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:). When you create an `SKAction` instance ahead of time, it does all the necessary prep to perform the action (in this case, playing a sound) without lag during gameplay. To run the action (play the sound), call `runAction`  on a node — this can be any node, even the scene itself.

Since it doesn't matter which node you use for sound purposes, use whichever is most convenient. For example, if you're just playing a sound you might call `runAction` on the scene. But if your sound is part of an action group or sequence that, say, animates a sprite, you could make the sound action part of that sequence and play it on the sprite that you're animating.

See [SpriteKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/AddingActionstoSprites/AddingActionstoSprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH11-SW1) for more about actions.

---

<sup>Unrelated Swift tip: use `let` instead of `var` for references that won't change. It can help keep you from introducing bugs later, and it probably helps the compiler optimize your code, too.</sup>

Comment: I added this to where the contact between the hero and the coin occur and I get an error:            let playSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("coin", waitForCompletion: true)

Comment: This is the error I get:       *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Resource coin cannot be found in the main bundle'

Comment: It works I forgot to put the .wav. Thanks it works perfectly!

Comment: Could I stop the sound also because my game collects coins after the hero dies and I want the sound not to play when this happens? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to cut off any currently playing sound when the hero dies, or prevent collisions with a dead hero from playing sound? For the former, see [`runAction:withKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/runAction:withKey:) and [`removeActionForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/removeActionForKey:). For the latter, check whether the hero is dead before you play your sound.

Comment: Yes I want cut sound when the hero is dead. I tried removeAvtionForKey but it still plays the sound.

Answer (score 0):

you should not be calling prepareToPlay on the collision,  prepareToPlay sets up the sound buffer, do that in your didMoveToView function

Comment: there still is a lag in my game when I put the prepareToPlay in the didMoveToView.