# Game Lags when player jumps for first time

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

My game has a very short lag when the player jumps the first time in the game. That's the code in the jump function:

```
if(canJump){
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 130))
    playSound(action: SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("jump_sound.mp3", waitForCompletion: false))
}
```

When I remove the line of code that plays the sound, the lag is fixed. Which means I need so somehow load the sound before it gets played the first time, how would I do that?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29585638/5924181) may be helpful.

Comment: Yes it helped me, thanks :)